# Select by Convert data to show them

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I use this code to retrieve my info

```
select * from mp_log
where
START_TIME='13-OCT-12 02.28.56.615000000 PM';
```

but now I want search it only by this word : `'2012-02-24'`

would you please write correct syntax

Comment: I use Oracle to search it

Comment: I try with this : '20120224' but not working

Comment: What is the data type of that column `START_TIME`??

Comment: START_TIME data type is 'TIMESTAMP(6)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't compare a string and a timestamp, use [to_timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm) function instead.

If you want to truncate the time value an leave only the date use trunc function.

Try:

```
select * from mp_log
where trunc(START_TIME) = to_timestamp( '20120224', 'yyyymmdd')
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7eef7/4)

Comment: I'd prefer `start_time between a and b` over `trunc(START_TIME) = a`

Comment: @beherenow, thanks for your comment, if there is an index on start_time it's better. Though you can also have a `function based index`

Answer (score 1):

plz try this one,

trunc(date_column)=trunc(to_date('23-feb-2014','DD-MON-YYYY'));

OR

trunc(date_column)=to_date('23-feb-2014','DD-MON-YYYY');